# Drag and Drop compressed files from swing to native [update]

Tags: java, drag-and-drop

I am trying to move files from a compressed archive to the native system (basycally, windows' eplorer) through drag and drop operations.

My only idea at this moment is to create a TransferHandler, which, when launched, will decompress the file in a temporary directory and set up that file as Transferable. Here is a snippet of code to make myself more clear:

```
private class FileTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
    protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
        List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

        try {
            File temp = createTempDirectory();
            String path = temp.getAbsolutePath();
            decompressTo(path);
            files.add(new File(path));
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); };
        return new FileTransferable(files);
    }

    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        return COPY;
    }
}

private class FileTransferable implements Transferable {
    private List<File> files;

    public FileTransferable(List<File> files) {
       this.files = files;
    }

    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
        return new DataFlavor[]{ DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor };
    }

    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
        return flavor.equals(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
    }

    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
        if (!isDataFlavorSupported(flavor)) {
            throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
        }
        return files;
    }
}
```

(not valid anymore: The thing that puzzles me is that this way it somehow works: but only if after I release the mouse button I am not doing anything else.)

update: After more testing I observed that actually the file data is transferred from the temp directory to destination after I click in a zone that accepts that DataFlavor. If I click in a folder, the temp files are transferred to that folder. If I click in the console window, the path to the temp file appears in the console window.

So, if you please, I would like some pointers to direct me in the right way.

p.s.: the idea with decompressing to temp folder first came after observing that WinRar is doing the same thing.

p.p.s.: sorry if the question seems stupid, but I am mostly a web programmer just dabbling in desktop programming.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not doing anything else". When does it fail? If you move the mouse? If you don't release the mouse button? When you click somewhere?

Comment: Click somewhere else, open other windows while the decompressing is working, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is apparently nearing the best results you can get.
I'll check your code when I have some time for it.